# Is there a way to specify the width of a rectangle in PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, draw

I'm trying to draw thick rectangles onto an image using ImageDraw Module of PIL/pillow.

I tried using `draw.rectangle([x1, y1, x2, y2], outline='yellow', width=3)` but it doesn't seem to like the width parameter.

I can emulate what I want to do with a bunch of lines, but I was wondering if there is a proper way of doing it.

```
'''
coordinates = [(x1, y1), (x2, y2)]

    (x1, y1)
        *--------------
        |             |
        |             |
        |             |
        |             |
        |             |
        |             |
        --------------*
                      (x2, y2)

'''

def draw_rectangle(drawing, xy, outline='yellow', width=10):
    top_left = xy[0]
    bottom_right = xy[1]
    top_right = (xy[1][0], xy[0][1])
    bottom_left= (xy[0][0], xy[1][1])

    drawing.line([top_left, top_right], fill=outline, width=width)
    drawing.line([top_right, bottom_right], fill=outline, width=width)
    drawing.line([bottom_right, bottom_left], fill=outline, width=width)
    drawing.line([bottom_left, top_left], fill=outline, width=width)
```

Answer (score 27):

**UPDATE** - Pillow >= 5.3.0 `rectangle` now supports the `width` argument:
`PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.rectangle(xy, fill=None, outline=None, width=0)`

**Previous answer:**

Here is a method that draws a first initial rectangle, and then further rectangles going inwards - note, the line width is **not** centered along the border.

```
def draw_rectangle(draw, coordinates, color, width=1):
    for i in range(width):
        rect_start = (coordinates[0][0] - i, coordinates[0][1] - i)
        rect_end = (coordinates[1][0] + i, coordinates[1][1] + i)
        draw.rectangle((rect_start, rect_end), outline = color)

# example usage

im = Image.open(image_path)
drawing = ImageDraw.Draw(im)

top_left = (50, 50)
bottom_right = (100, 100)

outline_width = 10
outline_color = "black"

draw_rectangle(drawing, (top_left, bottom_right), color=outline_color, width=outline_width)
```

Answer (score 9):

PIL rectangle now support `width` parameter.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

height = width = 800
img = Image.new('RGB', (height, width), (255, 255, 255))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
draw.rectangle([100,100,500,400], width = 10, outline="#0000ff")
img.show()
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of four lines you can also draw one line with four points, making a rectangle:

```py
def drawrect(drawcontext, xy, outline=None, width=0):
    (x1, y1), (x2, y2) = xy
    points = (x1, y1), (x2, y1), (x2, y2), (x1, y2), (x1, y1)
    drawcontext.line(points, fill=outline, width=width)

# example
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
im = Image.new("RGB", (150, 150), color="white")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)

drawrect(draw, [(50, 50), (100, 100)], outline="red", width=5)

im.show()
```

Comment: I am using PIL v1.1.7 and pillow v 5.3.0 and drawing a rectangle with lines produces has missing pixels in the corners. I think there is still a bug in the line drawing algorithm. A better approach is to draw rectangles of increasing size in a loop to approximate the width parameter. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

This method works with PIL v1.1.7 and pillow v 5.3.0 on Ubuntu 18.04. The corners are not square, but at least the are only off by 1/2 pixel as opposed to the approach of drawing 4 lines with a width parameter to create a rectangle, which is off by at least 1 pixel is each corner. I think there is still a bug in the line drawing algorithm in pillow/pil.

```
def drawrect(drawcontext, xy, color=None, width=1):
    (x1, y1), (x2, y2) = xy
    offset = 1
    for i in range(0, width):
        drawcontext.rectangle(((x1, y1), (x2, y2)), outline=color)
        x1 = x1 - offset
        y1 = y1 + offset
        x2 = x2 + offset
        y2 = y2 - offset
```

and then in your code you would have:

```
# example
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
im = Image.new("RGB", (150, 150), color="white")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)

drawrect(draw, [(50, 50), (100, 100)], outline="red", width=5)
del draw
im.show()
```

Thanks to gdwarf for his solution which put me on the path to this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw a view rects e.g:

```
draw.rectangle([(x, y),(x+w,y+h) ], outline=(0,0,255,255))
draw.rectangle([(x+1, y+1),(x+w-1,y+h-1) ], outline=(0,0,255,255))
draw.rectangle([(x+2, y+2),(x+w-2,y+h-2) ], outline=(0,0,255,255))
...
```

of cause in a loop and a function.